# Crystal Report Chart Wrong Data

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Report chart information does not match up with actual values.

At first when graphing my values it was forcing it to be summarized, but I found a solution where I use a formula to equal the un-summarized data.

Equation Used: numberVar Value := {vData.Value}

However now when I try graphing using the formula, the chart is showing incorrect data. The data should be ranging from around 38-42 but the highest value the chart goes to is 40.

[Image of Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRUy2.png)

[Image of Chart with tighter date parameters. Only 50 values and values should be between 38 and 41](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoxqw.png)

Comment: We're going to need more information to help you.  Pease describe the design of your report, including what sections/groupings you are using, and where the formula and chart are located within the design of the report.  A sample of the dataset may also help.

You may also want to check the value returned by your formula in the report to make certain the expected value is being returned for each data row if you haven't already done so.  Be mindful of any rounding or loss of precision in decimal values while doing this.  There shouldn't be any, but its good to rule it out.